# how to preview many pictures in a same time?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code but I can only preview one image but I want to preview multiple images at a same time. here is my code

```js
var loadFile = function(event) {
  var image = document.getElementById('output');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" 
  onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none" />
</p>
<button>
  <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer">Upload to Album two</label>
</button>
<p><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to dynamically create the image and append it to a wrapper object (in this case a paragraph) instead of using a precreated image tag.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('output');
var loadFile = function (event) {
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  target.appendChild(image)
};
```

```html
 <p>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        name="image"
        id="file"
        onchange="loadFile(event)"
        style="display: none"
      />
    </p>
    <button>
      <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer">Upload to Album two</label>
    </button>
    <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: And then when done, each image has to be added to a formdata